# reordering UITableView cells and tracking the index

Tags: swift, uitableview, indexing

I have an array of words that are displayed in a UITableView in a specific order word1, word2, word3, word4, word5 etc. There is a property of each word in Core data called wordIndex, that tracks the index of each word so a user can edit the table and change the word order. I am trying to use moveRowAtIndexPath to update the wordIndex of all words in the table everytime a move is made, but this method doesn't appear to use indexPath.row. Thanks in advance if anyone has come across a slick way to do this?

The code I have is:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let wordToMove = words[sourceIndexPath.row]
    words.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    words.insert(wordToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)

    wordToMove.wordIndex = destinationIndexPath.row // seems to always have an index of 2
 // and what about updating all the other indexes above and below the moved word? 
 // indexPath.row is not allowed in this method to iterate over all the rows in the table....

    for words[(indexPath.row) == 0]; words[(indexPath.row) = words.count]; words[(indexPath.row)++] { 
        word?.wordIndex = indexPath.row
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    coreDataStack.saveMainContext()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fromIndexPath.row` and `toIndexPath.row` instead.